# Find next td containing an image

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img>
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img>
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on an image, I need to find the next row which has a td containing an image, and add another row before it.
I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$(this)
  .closest("tr")
  .next("tr:has(td:has(img))")
  .before("<tr><td style='border-right: hidden'></td><td colspan='999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is almost correct, you just need to use `nextAll()` as the element you're looking for is not the next sibling. You'll just need to use `:first` as well if you want to find the next instance only. Finally,`tr:has(img)` is all you need to find the row, there's no need for `td:has()` as well. Try this:

```js
$('img').click(function() {      
  $(this).closest("tr").nextAll("tr:has(img):first").before('<tr><td style="border-right:hidden"></td><td colspan="999">' + $(this).next().html() + '</td></tr>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="foo.jpg">
      <div>div 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="foo.jpg">
      <div>div 2</div>
    </td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current index of your image inside the TR. I suggest using classes though but this will suffice if this is what you need.  I have added an alt text and border just to see what is happening

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>    
<table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td><img alt="sample"><div></div></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img alt="sample"><div></div></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

For the JS code, I have used delegate just in case the image added also needs to be clicked. Here I get the current index and then checked if there is a next item then incremented it to the next.

```
$("table").on('click','img',function(){
  //get current index
  var index = $("tr img").index(this);

  //get total item count 
  var count = $("tr img").length;
  //check if has next tr with img
  if (index < (count - 1)){
    index++;
    //we need to get the next tr with image then move element up to parent tr to insert row before it
    $("tr img:eq("+ index + ")").closest('tr').before('<tr><td><img alt="sample_new"><div></div></td> <td></td><td></td></tr>');
  }
});
```

When running this you will see that a new row is added before the next row with image. 
You can find the working code [here](https://jsbin.com/getacudija/edit?html,js,output)

For efficiency you might want to use [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to duplicate a hidden blank row instead so that it would be easier to edit.